# MSBuild fails with /p:OutDir parameter

Tags: visual-studio-2015, msbuild

In VS2015 I created a test C++ console application 'Kon' (New Project->Visual C++->Win32->Win32 Console Application).

If I start MSBuild with /p:OutDir parameter, it fails all the time:

*C:\examples\Kon>**msbuild /p:Configuration="Release" /p:OutDir="C:\out\"**

Microsoft (R) Build Engine version 14.0.25420.1
Copyright (C) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.
Building the projects in this solution one at a time. To enable parallel build, please add the "/m" switch.
Build started 5/8/2018 4:29:00 PM.
Project "C:\examples\Kon\Kon.sln" on node 1 (default targets).
ValidateSolutionConfiguration:
  Building solution configuration "Release|x64".
Project "C:\examples\Kon\Kon.sln" (1) is building "C:\examples\Kon\Kon\Kon.vcxproj" (2) on node 1 (default targets).
C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(31,5): **error MSB4184: The expression "[System.IO.Path]::Combine(C:\examples\Kon\Kon\, C:\out"\Kon.exe)" c
annot be evaluated. Illegal characters in path.** [C:\examples\Kon\Kon\Kon.vcxproj]
Done Building Project "C:\examples\Kon\Kon\Kon.vcxproj" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Done Building Project "C:\examples\Kon\Kon.sln" (default targets) -- FAILED.
Build FAILED.
"C:\examples\Kon\Kon.sln" (default target) (1) ->
"C:\examples\Kon\Kon\Kon.vcxproj" (default target) (2) ->
  C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V140\Microsoft.CppCommon.targets(31,5): error MSB4184: The expression "[System.IO.Path]::Combine(C:\examples\Kon\Kon\, C:\out"\Kon.exe)"
 cannot be evaluated. Illegal characters in path. [C:\examples\Kon\Kon\Kon.vcxproj]
    0 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)
Time Elapsed 00:00:00.12*

I am getting the same error with all kinds of C++ projects including MFC and ATL, but C# projects build fine with this option.

Comment: Try giving OutDir parameter without double quotes like this /p:OutDir=C:\out\

Comment: Great! It works!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you look at

> error MSB4184: The expression
>   "[System.IO.Path]::Combine(C:\examples\Kon\Kon\, C:\out"\Kon.exe)" 
>   cannot be evaluated. Illegal characters in path.

There is double quote in middle of path. So if you remove double quotes from OutDir parameter like this /p:OutDir=C:\out then it should work as expected.